# Is there a open source php auction platform/site?

Tags: php

Is there a open source php auction platform/site? Like Boonex Dolphin for a social network site; how about for a bid/auction site? Where users can post and bid on items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might help: http://www.webidsupport.com/